# Calling Stored procedure using Nhibernate -- Getting exception No persister for:

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate

here is code, how I am calling Stored procedure

```
ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        IQuery q = session.GetNamedQuery("ps_getProgressBarData1");
        var t = q.List();
```

XML mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"   namespace="ReleaseDAL"  assembly="ReleaseDAL">

 <sql-query name="ps_getProgressBarData1">
    <return alias="ProgressBar" class="ProgressBar">
      <return-property name="Tot" column="Tot"/>
      <return-property name="subtot" column="subtot"/>
    </return>
    exec ps_getProgressBarData1
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class mapping

```
public virtual Int32 Tot {get { return _Tot; } set { _Tot = value; } }
    public virtual Int32 subtot { get { return _subtot; } set { _subtot = value; }}
```

I am getting exception: `No persister for: ReleaseDAL.ProgressBar, ReleaseDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

Please tell me what is the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get that error you don't have the mapping file marked as `embedded resource`. Please check that as first thing.

Comment: yes, that's very good point, now I am getting this issue -------No persister for: ReleaseDAL.ProgressBar, ReleaseDAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: Please check this other question on the site and tell me if works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57804/nhibernate-mappingexception-no-persister-for

Comment: no, this is not working for me. I have already check this. I am upvoting becoz ur first clue working for, now I am getting other issue of No persister for: ReleaseDAL.ProgressBar

Comment: The class ProgressBar is on the namespace "ReleaseDAL"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm running out of ideas. Maybe you can paste the ProgressBar mapping and check also if this mapping file is marked as embedded resource

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have a mapping for ProgressBar (it's not an entity I suppose), so probably you just want a DTO as a result from the query.

So you just have to map the result as scalars, and in the query define a transformer.

```
 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="ReleaseDAL"  assembly="ReleaseDAL">

 <sql-query name="ps_getProgressBarData1">
      <return-scalar column="Tot" Type="xxx"/>
      <return-scalar column="subtot" Type="xxx"/>

    exec ps_getProgressBarData1
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and in the query methode:

```
query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(ProgressBar )));
query.List()
```