# NHibernate mapping exception. No persister for: NHibernateTesting.Account

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, unit-of-work

I'm just trying to start learning NHibernate, and while testing with an extremely simple POCO I'm already having issues. I'm getting the No Persister exception, here is what my code looks like:

`Account` table:

```
create table Account
(
    AccountID int primary key identity(1,1),
    AccountName varchar(10),
    CreateDate datetime
)
go
```

`Account` class:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual int AccountID { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public Account()
    {
        AccountID = 0;
        AccountName = "";
        CreateDate = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

Mapping file, `Account.hbm.xml` (yes, it's embedded into assembly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   namespace="NHibernateTesting" assembly="NHibernateTesting">
  <class name="Account" table="Account">
    <id name="AccountID">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="AccountName" />
    <property name="CreateDate" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Config section in config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">My connection string</property>

      <mapping assembly="NHibernateTesting" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Finally, the code making the call:

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.GetASession())
{
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var newAccount = new Account();
        newAccount.AccountName = "some name";

        session.Update(newAccount); // Exception thrown here.

        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or why I would be getting this exception, I've read on the web the issue is related to mapping, but I just can't see what wrong in this example.

Comment: Maybe the Hibernate session is not being configured properly? Can you give the source of the NHibernateHelper?

Comment: By the way, whenever you create a new instance, you should call session.Save or session.SaveOrUpdate instead of session.Update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reproduced all the mapping and code as you've shown, and it is working. Except:

```
var newAccount = new Account(); // NEW
...
session.Update(newAccount); // Update throws exception:
```

> NHibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row
>   count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

New object must be saved via: `session.Save(newAccount);`

When you say, that the mapping file is marked as embedded resource... it is hard to say what exactly is wrong. Please, try to carefully follow this link (and re-check your project), with a pretty good experience chain about the **No persister** excepiton:

- [NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57804/1679310)

Comment: Something must've been wrong with the project itself where the compiler wasn't picking up the mapping document, because I created another console project EXACTLY the same as project with a 2 added at the end of the name (NHibernateTesting2) and it worked just fine. WTH VS2012?!

Comment: Yes, that is possible, these "incorrectness" are hard to find. Glad to see that you've managed to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because of invalid mapping configuration. You should check where you set .Mappings for your session factory. Basically search for ".Mappings(" in your project and make sure you specified correct entity class in below line.

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<YourEntityClassName>())
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing my column name to **Id**. As i had first done **TemplateId** so it displayed this error but when i changed the field to **Id** it got solved. So it is the requirement of nhibernate or Orchard to have identity field or primary key as **Id**.