# Fluent NHibernate add assembly runtime

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

I have the following structure in Visual Studio

```
Control (Solution)
  AppDB (Project)
    Classes (Folder)
       Piece.cs
    Mapping (Folder)
       PieceMap.cs
```

I add the assembly map at runtime doing the following instructions

```
Configuration hibernateConfiguration = new Configuration();
hibernateConfiguration.SetProperty("connection.connection_string", "server=(local);Data Source="+pRutaDB);
hibernateConfiguration.AddAssembly("AppDB.Mapping.PieceMap");
hibernateConfiguration = hibernateConfiguration.Configure();
NHibernate.ISessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
NHibernate.ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
NHibernate.ITransaction tr = session.BeginTransaction();
Piece p = new Piece();
p.name = "Test Piece";
pSession.SaveOrUpdate(p);
tr.Commit();
```

But when the tr.Commit() instruction arrives, thew following error shows up

```
Error: NHibernate.MappingException: Could not add assembly AppDb.Mapping.PieceMap ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

Anyone can tell me how to add the assembly at runtime?

Thanks!

Edit: with the instruction the error changed `hibernateConfiguration.AddAssembly(typeof(GeometriaDB.Mapping.PieceMap).Assembly);`

Now the following error appears:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for: GeometriaDB.Clases.Proyecto
```

So now why is that error appearing?

Comment: Your next error has probably nothing to do with the first, better ask a dedicated question for it.

Comment: But ensure first it is not already replied, as [in this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57804/1178314).

Answer (score 0):

At least you should add .dll to assembly name:

```
hibernateConfiguration.AddAssembly("AppDB.Mapping.PieceMap.dll");
```

And also dll should be in same directory or you should show full path to assembly.

Another way you can use is:

```
hibernateConfiguration.AddAssembly(typeof(AppDB.Mapping.PieceMap.<and any class name>).Assembly);
```

Comment: Why to add .dll if the mapping is a cs file?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I think when you show parameter as string, nhibernate try to load assembly from file.

Comment: I've tried with the first possibility but it didn't work. Now the second one seem to work but it fires a new Exception. I'm updating the initial post with the new Exception

Comment: `PieceMap` is `public` and inheriting from correct base class? Also does `Proyecto` have a mapping?

Comment: The problem now with mappings. You should add mappings.